# why is my pi broken?

Tags: sd-card

guys, I think my sd card is corrupted my pi won't boot and suddenly stopped working.  I couldn't connect via ssh or vnc to it (I could do this, but when I came back from the toilet I couldn't anymore)

Comment: what is the point of mentioning the toilet? ... do you think that had something to do with the failure? .... how do you know that your Pi is broken?

Comment: Before assuming your RPi is broken due to your comfort break. Start by reading the collective knowledge from seven years of why a RPi may not boot: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: that must've been a hell of an "ablution" to cause such damage to the pi

Answer (score 1):

The OS in Pi can get corrupted for many many reasons.  My Raspbian OS got corrupted two times in front of me and I couldn't have the time to pay a visit  to the  toilet.